# Merged Mining Disadvantages

Tags: mining-pools, namecoin, p2pool, merged-mining

What are the disadvantages of merged mining? I'm very interested in p2pool and since I have to "run my own server" I've been considering enabling merged mining.

Besides the obvious administration overhead and learning (which I chalk up to being a hobby), what disadvantages are there? I wouldn't be reducing my BTC hashrate would I?

Comment: [You might find this useful](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=62842.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disadvantage of merged mining is the additional coin daemons you have to run in the background. They all use disk space, memory, cpu cycles and bandwidth. A more annoying issue is that most of them are no longer maintained and have bugs. You may find that they crash frequently - at least namecoind does.